# What does “make it cross” mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I believe it's a British phrase.

I found it in [that](http://www.buyacar.co.uk/cars/fiat/fiat_panda/category_429.jhtml) website, as:

> Fiat's Panda can offer an affordable route into 4x4 ownership. You just have to make it Cross.

If you happen to know more meanings except for the one example I've provided, please let me know.

Comment: Just to make it clear: _Fiat Panda_ is the brand of a car.

Comment: It, here, probably refers to the fact that being a good on-road vehicle, Panda serves as an affordable 4 wheel drive vehicle. But, to check it out for real, you have to take it off-road (Cross Country kinds).

Comment: It's not a British phrase: at least, not this Brit. I have had it explained to me (below), but I still can't say I understand it.

Comment: It makes a world of difference if the original quote had the word *Cross* with a capital *C*, as it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pun. "Make it cross" without context would mean "Make it angry"; but the second meaning here is "Make it a Fiat Panda Cross rather than just a Fiat Panda".

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say

Comment: It looks like a double pun, given the British children's joke "How do you make a Maltese Cross with only one match?" which suggests a mathematical construction puzzle but has the answer "Light his trousers."

Answer (score 2):

This is a really weird marketing slogan.

The car (the Fiat Panda Cross) is meant to be an urban 4x4, which means it's good for urban driving, but it also has some off-road capability, so Panda Cross hints that it's cross-purpose (has multiple uses) and is a kind of cross (mongrel/mix breed).

So I guess you could say that 'make it cross' in this context either means push it to do more rugged, off-road things (make it angry?), or make it cross (over) from one driving environment to another.

Answer (score 1):

It's a play on words between *make it cross [the route, the street, the path]* and *make it Cross*, meaning *to change to four-wheel drive*, or *change from gasoline to methane*.

Comment: Is "make it Cross" meaning "change to four-wheel drive" familiar to you? Because it is completely unknown to me.

Comment: In this specific case, I would understand _make it cross_ as _make it change state_, as in _change from two-wheel drive to four-wheel drive_.

Comment: @Colin Fine: it's only really meaningful in the context of the review (of the car).